# I do not get it these queries look the same to me. What is the difference between these queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For questions below, use the following schema definition.

- restaurant (rid, name, phone, street, city, state, zip)
- customer (cid, fname, lname, phone, street, city, state, zip)
- carrier (crid, fname, lname, lp)
- delivery (did, rid, cid, tim, size, weight)
- pickup (did, tim, crid)
- dropoff (did, tim, crid)

It's a schema for a food delivery business that employs food carriers (carrier table).

Customers (customer table) order food from restaurants (restaurant table).

The restaurants order a delivery (delivery table); to deliver food from restaurant to customer.

The pickup table records when carrier picks up food at restaurant.

The dropoff table records when carrier drops off food at customer.

1. Find customers who did not have any deliveries for 3 months.

a.

```
select c.cid 
from customer c 
  left outer join delivery d 
  on c.cid=d.cid 
where d.tim >= (now()-interval '3 months') and d.did is null;
```

b.

```
select c.cid 
from customer c 
  natural left outer join delivery d 
where d.tim >= (now()-interval '3 months') and d.did is null;
```

c.

```
select c.cid 
from customer c 
  left outer join delivery d 
  using(cid) and d.tim >= (now()-interval '3 months') 
where d.did is not null;
```

d.

```
select c.cid 
from customer c 
  left outer join delivery d 
  on c.cid=d.cid and d.tim >= (now()-interval '3 months') 
where d.did is null;
```

e. (write your own answer)

Comment: a and b are poor tables aliases. I'd chose something that makes sense, like c for customer and d for delivery.

Comment: Most people recommend to not use `natural join`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Why do folks not recommend `natural join`?

Comment: @AndyLester . . . Because it hides the columns used for `join`ing.  It is really easy to make mistakes.  And worse, it is not "natural" because it does not use properly declared foreign key relationships -- the *natural* relationships between tables.

Comment: If you ran `from restaurant natural join customer` it would join on the columns phone, street, city, state and zip - rather useless I think.

Comment: If you come here with your homework questions, please show at least some attempt to solve it yourself.

Comment: great advice on the natural join!

Comment: But how does that affect this problem a and b still both look correct because cid is the only thing they have in common to join